# How do you split "cities" into morphemes?

Tags: morphology, learning, split

Would it be "cit/ies" or "citie/s"? I'm just starting morphology and I got confused about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plural noun *cities* may be divided into two morphemes:

*cit(y)* -  **free** morpheme (also known as the *root word*)
*-ies* - **bound** morpheme (also identified as a *suffix*)

This type of morphological process is *inflectional* because there has been a grammatical change to the root word: pluralisation (or an increase in number).

Also note that *city* has an irregular plural form in writing (not speech) as, by convention, if the word ends in *a consonant + y* then 'y' changes to 'ies'.

Not entirely relevant to your question but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought the plural form would interfere in the morphological analysis of that word.

Comment: Not a problem :) No, the plural form is what is most interesting about your example and its morphological composition! Otherwise, it would just be a free morpheme _city_.

Answer (score 3):

“Cities” is the plural inflected form of “city”. It has two morphemes: *city* + the noun-pluralizing morpheme, here realized as the suffix /z/. The spelling change of Y to IE is irrelevant to the morphological analysis.

If you really need to split up the written form, I think you could argue for either the division “citi-es” or “citie-s”. I don’t see any reason to think of the letter I as representing part of the second morpheme, so I would not agree with the division “cit-ies”.